# IF statement fails

Tags: php, apache, php4

I have created a simple a php script I do not understand what could be wrong with it. I believe it should echo "Died!" because the die function is executed right

```
if (die()){
    echo "Died!";
}
```

Please help, thanks.
(I'm currently using php 4.3.9 and apache)

Comment: if the die function has executed ... well ahum ... , the process died ! never getting to the echo.

Comment: ich ... did you really mean 4.3.9 ?  if you are learning php, i would highly recommend that you start with latest stable version.

Comment: yes we are using 4.3.9 in production
(our client wanted us to use it)

Comment: @AbdulBaariel-Shad PHP 4.3 has been unsupported since 2005. Using it will expose you to 13 years of unfixed security issues. Do not use it. If your client insists, find another client.

Comment: my company is bankrupt can't afford to loose another client

Answer (score 0):

Die is equivalent to exit(), per PHP:

"exit — Output a message and terminate the current script"

The script should terminate before evaluation is complete and the echo will never happen.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

There may be a few exceptions that work around this, but it is safe to say die is the last thing to be executed, not echo.

Since the script is stopping, the return will not happen, exit stating "No value is returned.".

Comment: There is nothing to work. echo will not fire, that is how it works.

Comment: @AbdulBaariel-Shad ... you seem so certain that people are wrong, yet you have an issue you cant explain !!! maybe , just maybe, consider **you** are wrong.

Comment: sorry dude, this is how it works. This sandbox goes down to 4.4, same result. 
 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c62b4bba420deee3b5feeb8efcfa2fb53bed8680

Comment: clearly that emulator is wrong because it is 4.4 and 4.3.9
also I'm neber wrong

Comment: There is nothing wrong with making a mistake. I can confirm that exit (which die is an alias of) will output a string if you pass them as a parameter and will not if you do them after. You don't have to take our word for it, it is all documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: that's not official in fact my built in browser security that website has a keylogger (using coccoc)